# Set permissions by role in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to create 4 different roles in Azure SQL database. The 4 role names are READ_ONLY_ACCESS, READ_UPDATE_ACCESS,  READ_WRITE_UPDATE_ACCESS, FULL_ACCESS.

-READ_ACCESS - Grant Select
-READ_UPDATE_ACCESS - Grant Select, Update
-READ_WRITE_UPDATE_ACCESS - Grant select, Update, Insert
-FULL_ACCESS - Grant Select, Update, Insert, Delete

My goal is to create these 4 roles with these permissions, and then be able to create a user assigned to one of these roles. Example below of what I want to do after creating these roles:

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD = 'password';

ALTER ROLE READ_ACCESS ADD MEMBER username;
```

I've found a few sites that help with this, but I'm unclear as to whether or not I need to declare whether to deny access to certain permissions as well as declaring the granted access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create roles.

```
create role ApplicationUsers_ReadAccss;
grant select on schema::dbo to ApplicationUsers_ReadAccss;

create role ApplicationUsers_ReadUpdateAccss;
grant select, update on schema::dbo to ApplicationUsers_ReadUpdateAccss;

create role ApplicationUsers_ReadWriteUpdateAccss;
grant select, insert, update on schema::dbo to ApplicationUsers_ReadWriteUpdateAccss;

create role ApplicationUsers_FullAccess;
grant select, insert, update, delete, execute on schema::dbo to ApplicationUsers_FullAccess;
```

After that create logins and add them to one of the roles.

```
--create a server-level Login

create login AppUser with Password ='asdfAds01980(*)(*)(#&$)#@';

--add a user mapped to that login in each database 

create user AppUser for login AppUser;
alter role ApplicationUsers_FullAccess add member AppUser;
```

Comment: @dlimes, your original create user statement with a password will work too, authenticating at the database level. You don't necessarily need a login.